# Google Map API v3, changing map type by clicking the link: "map is not defined"

Tags: maps

I'm using simpliest example from the official documentation:

```
function initialize() {
  var mapCent = new google.maps.LatLng($shirota, $dolgota);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: $uvelichenie,
    center: mapCent,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
      myOptions);
}
```

I've added this to change map type dynamically as described in the official documentation:

```
function perekluchitDor() {
    map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP);
}
```

This into a href in HTML part:

`onclick="perekluchitDor();">`

Everything is pretty simple, but still doesn't work. All that I can see is the error "map is not defined" when I click the link.

I wonder what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variable scope issue.  You need to declare `map` outside of your functions, as below (1st line of code).

```
      var map;  
      function initialize() {
          var mapCent = new google.maps.LatLng($shirota, $dolgota);
          var myOptions = {
            zoom: $uvelichenie,
            center: mapCent,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
          };

          map = new google.maps.Map(
            document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            myOptions);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var name1 = "value";
name1 = "value";
```

Used outside of a user-defined function, both of these do exactly the same. Both
create a global variable. A global variable can be accessed from any function in any
window or frame that is currently loaded. If we use var name1 inside a user-defined
function it is local in scope, we only can see it inside the function.

You need to only remove var, behined from map statement. You don't need to declare map outside of your functions.